# Jquery progress bar that work with respect to time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need a progress that works with time ... for example: If I give start time and end time, then progress bar works with that time.

Example:

```
start_time = 3:30 pm
end_time = 4:10 pm
total_time = end_time - start_time
```

And progress bar should complete with respect to `total_time` and also total time is must in minutes. I have trying this [plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Easy-jQuery-Progress-Bar-Timer-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-progressTimer.html).

But its not work much for me...

Comment: share your code with this question

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would give to you as a direction, it updates only once a minute so if you don't see the progressbar moving wait for it :) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2g4tdmo4/2/)

HTML

```
  <div id="prbar"><span id="fill"></span>
  </div><span id="showleftmin"></span>
```

CSS

```
#prbar {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 10px;
}

#fill {
    width:0px;
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
    display:block;
}
```

Javascript

```
var start = parseInt("2325", 0); //start time
var end = parseInt("2350", 0); //end time

var totalminutes = end - start;
var incrementer = 100/totalminutes;
var lengthprbar = 0;
var minutesleft = totalminutes;

var fill = document.getElementById('fill');

setInterval(function () {

    if (minutesleft === 0) {
        return;
    }

    lengthprbar += incrementer;

    fill.style.width = lengthprbar + 'px';

    document.getElementById('showleftmin').innerHTML = minutesleft - 1;

    minutesleft--;
}, 60000);
```

Comment: I wonder how much work is needed in order to get time intervals to work on the progress tag.

Comment: @Ammara Must be working now, althoug you have to figure out for yourself how to calculate the time. Say you have two hours, with this notation you get 200 minutes instead of 120 minutes. Keep in mind this is just a direction. Good luck.